# Dev C++ disabled new class option

Tags: c++, class, header, dev-c++

[image: help?...]

does anyone know why is this happening?
I want to create a header file with cpp file. i tried manualy, but i got an error in header file, saying unknown type name 'class'...

Comment: Most likely your project is set up targeting C instead of C++.

Comment: thanks, but how do i solve this problem?

Comment: My guess is you start a new project and specify C++, then you can create classes in that project.  It's a guess, because I have never used Dev-C++, I'm just making practical conjecture.

Comment: that works for me, but i want to create classes in an another file.. thanks though

Comment: Oh nevermind. solved (XD)

Answer (score -1):

for those of you are experiencing the same problem with me, i just found a solution to this problem XD. just create a new project.